# Code crashes after call to scanf

Tags: c, function

I'm a programming beginner and I need help with my code. It's supposed to be a calculator  with 6 functions including main. Four for the operations and one to take the input for two numbers. It crashes as soon as I enter the second input for the number. Also, I had a problem with returning the values from the function `input()` into the main function to perform the operations. Maybe it has something to do with scanning for opt?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int n1, int n2);
int subtract(int n1, int n2);
int multiply(int n1, int n2);
int divide(int n1, int n2);
void input(int *n1, int *n2);


int main(void)
{
    int n1, n2, ret;
    char opt;


    input(&n1, &n2);

    printf("Addition -> 1\nSubtraction -> 2\nMultiplication -> 3\nDivision -> 4\nReset -> R\nExit -> E\n");

    scanf("%c", &opt);



    switch(opt){
            case '1': 
                ret = add(n1, n2);
                printf("The sum is %d\n", ret);
                break;
            case '2':
                ret = subtract(n1, n2);
                printf("The difference is %d\n", ret);
                break;
            case '3': 
                ret = multiply(n1, n2);
                printf("The sum is %d\n", ret); 
                break;              
            case '4': 
                ret = divide(n1, n2);
                printf("The sum is %d\n", ret);
                break;
    }

    return 0;   

}


void input(int *n1, int *n2)
{
    int a, b;   

    printf("Enter first number: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n1);

    printf("Enter second number: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n2);   

    *n1 = a;
    *n2 = b;
}

add(n1, n2)
{
    int result;
    result = (n1+n2);
    return result;
}

subtract(n1, n2)
{
    int result;
    result = (n1-n2);
    return result;
}

divide(n1, n2)
{
    int result;
    result = (n1/n2);
    return result;
}

multiply(n1, n2)
{
    int result;
    result = (n1*n2);
    return result;
}
```

Am I even doing this right?

Comment: `scanf("%d", &n1);` --> `scanf("%d", &a);`, `scanf("%d", &n2);` --> `scanf("%d", &b);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in `input`:

```
printf("Enter first number: \n");
scanf("%d", &n1);

printf("Enter second number: \n");
scanf("%d", &n2);
```

The `%d` format specifier expects an `int *` argument.  Since `n1` and `n2` are already `int *`, that means `&n1` and `&n2` are of type `int **`.  That causes the segmentation fault.

To fix this, just pass in `n1` and `n2`:

```
void input(int *n1, int *n2)
{
    printf("Enter first number: \n");
    scanf("%d", n1);

    printf("Enter second number: \n");
    scanf("%d", n2);   

    getchar();
}
```

You'll notice that `a` and `b` are not required if you do this.  Also note the call to `getchar()` to consume the newline in the input buffer.  If you don't do that, the newline will get picked up by the `scanf` in `main` and the switch statement won't be entered.

Also, your four math functions don't specify a return type.  Since the prototypes for these function declare them as returning `int`, and because `int` is the default return type for a function, it manages to work.  However, you should always specify a return type.

Comment: @NobodyNada Thanks.  Fixed.

Comment: Hmmm... How do you specify a return type? Oh, and what is the asterisk for?

Comment: @fixotherm Put the return type right before the function name, the same way you do in the function prototypes at the top of your code:  `int add(int n1, int n2)`

Comment: @fixotherm If you're referring to `int *n1, int *n2` in the parameter list to `input`, that denotes a pointer type.  So `n1` in `input` contains the address of an `int`, namely that of `n1` in main.

Comment: Soooo, I should relpace void with int?

Comment: For `input`, no.  That function doesn't return anything, which is why its return type is `void`.

Comment: @dbush Ohh. Okay :) Wait. I don't get it. Sorry. Replace what with what?

Comment: @fixotherm `add`, `subtract`, `multiply`, and `divide` need an `int` return type.

Comment: can you give me an example how?

Comment: @fixotherm Like this:  `int add(int n1, int n2)`

Comment: Is there a way to get the values from function input instead of using the pointers?

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` takes pointers to integers but you incorrectly pass pointers to pointers to integers.

Fix:

```
void input(int *n1, int *n2)
{
    int a, b;   

    printf("Enter first number: \n");
    scanf("%d", n1);
```

and you don't need `a` and `b`, the values from input are directly written to what pointer points to. You have to read also the `'\n'` from input stream before call to `scanf("%c", &opt);` in *main* function. Otherwise you will read the newline then while you expected to read option character.

---

To address your question in comments:

```
int *n1
```

declares `n1` to be a *pointer* to integer.

Comment: Yaayyy!! :D Thanks :) It worked.
How do you do that? O.o
Rather, what does the * before n1 and n2 mean?

Comment: @fixotherm *n Indicates that you're accesing the value that is in the memory poition pointed by n. In this case `*n1 = a` means that `n1` will point to some portion of memory which inside has the value of `a`

Answer (score 1):

Your input function has a couple of problems:

```
void input(int *n1, int *n2)
{
    int a, b;   

    printf("Enter first number: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n1);
```

This is (most likely) the root cause of your crash.  The function parameter `n1` is *already* a pointer to `int`, and it contains the address of the thing you want to write to in `main`; `&n1` is a pointer to a pointer to `int`, and gives you the address *of the `n1` function parameter*.  So instead of writing an integer value into what `n1` *points to*, you wind up writing an integer value into `n1` itself.

Then, when you try to dereference the `n1` pointer and assign the thing it points to in

```
*n1 = a;
```

you wind up trying to access an invalid address, hence the crash.  You need to change your input line to the following:

```
    scanf( "%d", n1 ); // no & operator on n1
```

You have the same issue with the input for `n2`; you don't need the `&` here, since `n2` is already a pointer type.

Then we have this:

```
    *n1 = a;
    *n2 = b;
```

What do `a` and `b` contain at this point?  Whatever it is, assuming you fix the code above, you are going to overwrite whatever you already read into `*n1` and `*n2`.  Either get rid of these lines (and the declaration for `a` and `b`), or use `a` and `b` as the targets for your scanf calls:

```
    scanf( "%d", &a ); // a is not already a pointer, need the & operator
    ...
    scanf( "%d", &b ); // same as above
    ...
    *n1 = a;
    *n2 = b;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

scanf("%c", &opt); avoid this to get char as input..
rather use **scanf("%s", &opt);** to get the char inputs.

I think this answer is helpfull.

Comment: `%s` will scan a string.  He wants to scan a char.  Also, this doesn't answer the question of why `input()` crashes.